# Items in array do not update correctly if in a nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have the following sample code:

```
recs = []
for x in range(1,3):
    rec = {
        'A': x
    }
    recs.append(rec)
    print(rec)
    for y in range(1, 3):
        rec['B'] = y
        recs.append(rec)
        print(rec)

print('----- Array after exiting loops')
for r in recs:
    print(r)
```

This gives this output:

```
{'A': 1}
{'A': 1, 'B': 1}
{'A': 1, 'B': 2}
{'A': 2}
{'A': 2, 'B': 1}
{'A': 2, 'B': 2}
----- Array after exiting loops
{'A': 1, 'B': 2}
{'A': 1, 'B': 2}
{'A': 1, 'B': 2}
{'A': 2, 'B': 2}
{'A': 2, 'B': 2}
{'A': 2, 'B': 2}
```

Now I can resolve it with this code:

```
for y in range(1, 3):
    rec2 = rec.copy()
    rec2['B'] = y
    recs.append(rec2)
    print(rec2)
```

What I am looking for is explaining why this behaviour occurs when you go into a nested loop.

Comment: (1) you are working with lists; there is no array in your program.  (2) The problem is resolved by properly appending a `copy`; it has nothing to do with the nested loop.

Comment: This appears to be simplest answer from that link (in case anyone ever goes looking for the same thing). https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452923/1167890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your outer `x` loop, you are creating a new object with the `=` syntax. This loop only runs twice, so you end up with only two objects. For every run through the inner `y` loop, then, you are only modifying one of these first two objects.

Each time you update `rec['B']`, you are overwriting your previous changes to the object. When you append `rec` to `recs`, you are not creating a new object, you are just telling the list to include another reference to the same `rec` object.

If you print `recs` within your `y` loop instead of just `rec`, you can see this happen in real time.